# How to check matched annotation with StringList/ WordList in RUTA

Tags: nlp, uima, ruta, pega

I have a **Policy Number** of pattern:- AB-1234567-**PAD**; the **Product Code** is last **3** characters **(PAD)** of the Policy number.

With my code, I am now successfully extracting the **Product Code (PAD)** for given **format** of the **policy number**. But now I need to check the extracted **Product Code(PAD)** against the **list** of Product codes available. Currently, I am using `STRINGLIST`, which has list of product codes. But I don't know how to check whether the extracted Product Code has a match in the List of available Product codes.

Below is my code:

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

Document{->RETAINTYPE(SPACE)};


DECLARE Annotation ProdCode;

"(?i)\\b(?=.*\\d)[1]{0,1}[A-Z0-9]{2}[\\s |-]{0,2}[A-Z0-9]{7}[\\s |-]{0,2}([A-Z]{3})\\b"->1 = ProdCode; //<-Previously ProdCode was replaced with EntityType to get last 3 chars of given REGEX

STRINGLIST CustomSL = {"PLB","PAD"};

ProdCode{INLIST(CustomSL)->MARK(EntityType)}; //<- Requesting your help here!
```

Ex 1:

> Input: `The policy number is 1A-AB12345-PAD.`
>
> Expected output: `PAD`

Ex 2:

> Input: `The policy number is 1A-AB12345-PAN`.
>
> Expected output: Entity should not be recognized since PAN is not exist in
>   given STRINGLIST

Comment: I don't see what's the problem here. The `INLIST` condition should work as expected, i.e. you will get only `PAD` as `EntityType`. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: @user3711889 , Yes that's exactly what I need. But the above code is not working for me. I don't know whats wrong. FYI, I am new to RUTA. It would be really helpful if you share your thoughts regarding it. TIA :)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Try to remove `Document{->RETAINTYPE(SPACE)};` since you don't need it and let it run. Are you getting a `ProdCode` annotation for each of the examples?

Comment: Which Ruta version do you use?